# So many null value features while doing feature extraction using VGG19

Tags: keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, feature-extraction, vgg-net

I was working on an image recognition problem. After fine-tuned VGG19 and added few layers and trained the model. Upon achieving the best test accuracy, I saved the model, removed the last 6 layers, and extracted the activations of the last fully connected layer using the following code.

```
ROWS,COLS = 669,1026
input_shape = (ROWS, COLS, 3)

# train_data_dir = '/home/spectrograms/train'
validation_data_dir = '/home/spectrograms/test'
nb_train_samples = 791
nb_validation_samples = 198
# epochs = 200
batch_size = 10

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    input_shape = (3, ROWS, COLS)
else:
    input_shape = (ROWS, COLS,3)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)
validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(ROWS, COLS),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

model = Model(inputs=model.inputs, outputs=model.layers[-6].output)

predict = model.predict_generator(validation_generator,steps = 10)
print(predict[10])
print(predict[10].shape)
```

But the output vector has a lot of zeros.

```
[5.77765644e-01 2.44531885e-01 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00
 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00
 2.99371660e-01 8.27999532e-01 2.34099194e-01 2.67183155e-01
 0.00000000e+00 1.95847541e-01 4.49438214e-01 1.00336084e-02
 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 4.63756740e-01 0.00000000e+00
 0.00000000e+00 1.15372933e-01 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00
 1.13927014e-01 6.74777776e-02 7.49553144e-01 0.00000000e+00
 6.73675537e-02 2.85279214e-01 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00
 1.84553280e-01 4.57495511e-01 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00
 5.35506964e-01 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00
 2.92950690e-01 0.00000000e+00 5.27026653e-01 0.00000000e+00
 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 3.94881278e-01 0.00000000e+00
 5.37508354e-02 6.67039156e-02 1.16688050e-01 6.52413011e-01
 3.44565332e-01 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00
 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 1.10359691e-01 3.63592118e-01
 9.89193693e-02 1.15959466e-01 0.00000000e+00 1.57176346e-01
 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 2.90686011e-01
 0.00000000e+00 6.03572190e-01 1.97682872e-01 1.57113865e-01
 0.00000000e+00 2.84446061e-01 1.26254544e-01 0.00000000e+00
 0.00000000e+00 5.51187336e-01 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00
 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00
 1.11384936e-01 1.67153805e-01 2.63090044e-01 0.00000000e+00
 9.35753658e-02 9.16089058e-01 1.90610379e-01 0.00000000e+00
 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 3.04680824e-01 2.47930676e-01
 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00
 1.50975913e-01 3.60320956e-02 0.00000000e+00 3.47187579e-01
 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00
 3.01374853e-01 0.00000000e+00 2.38310188e-01 0.00000000e+00
 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 3.16582739e-01 0.00000000e+00
 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 8.17666354e-04
 2.30050087e-01 4.66496646e-01 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00
 1.05043598e-01 0.00000000e+00 6.77903090e-03 3.72976154e-01]
```

Is it normal? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems okay to me. The **positive non-zero values** that you've got in your output vector, those **are the activated neurons**. As the **activation** used in VGGNet **is mostly ReLU** (except the output layer), so the **output value** of any layer is **bounded between 0 or some positive value**.

#### *If you may recall, the relu functions is something like-*

```
def relu(z):
  return max(0, z)
```

So, as you see it squashes all the negative values to zero and lets only the positive values to pass.

Hence, It's very natural for all those values to be zero (jargon: In relu terms those are called **dead neurons** which is a big problem in RNN, and not so much in CNN)